# Не приходит данные именно из инпута type="email"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, формы

Сломал голову. Ничего не понимаю. 
Есть форма с двумя инпутами: телефон и мэйл. Отправляю по AJAX. Телефон приходит, а почта нет. И ни в какую. Пробовал менять name, имя переменной, даже на разных хостингах попробовал.. И ничего. Письмо приходит, но без почты. 
Подскажите, может я что-то упускаю?

Форма:

```
<form action="" class="delivery__form ajaxform2" method="post" >
    <input type="text" class="field" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__" name="phone">
    <input type="email" class="field" placeholder="Ваш E-mail " name="address">
    <div class="btn__cont">
        <input class="banner__order" type="submit" value="Зафиксировать цену">
    </div>
</form>
```

Php обработчик

```
<?php

$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$address = $_POST['address'];

$to = "почта";
$body = '
<html>
<head>
    <title>Заявка</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Заказ</h2>
    <ul>

        <li>Телефон: ' .$phone. '</li>
        <li>Телефон: ' .$address. '</li>

    </ul>
</body>
</html>';

$headers = 'From: ';

@mail($to,$headers, $body);
```

И JS

$(".ajaxform2").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

```
var input = $(this).find('input');
var form = $(this);
if (input.val() !== '') {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'send2.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: form.serialize(),
    success: function (data) {
    console.log('success');
      $.fancybox.open({
        src: '#modal4',
        type: 'inline',
      });
    },
    error: function () {
      console.log('hato');
    }
  });
}
```

});

Answer (score 2):

у вас ошибка, вы записываете данные в переменную

```
$address = $_POST['address'];
```

А в письмо вставляете

```
<li>Телефон: ' .$email. '</li>
```

Comment: Всё поправил. Разумеется такой ошибки нет. Это я неправильно скопировал.

Answer (score 1):

Сорри. Нашёл в чём косяк был. Проблема была в ненужном условии

```
if (input.val() !== '')
```